# Which programming languages are not supported by Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, programming-languages, eclipse-plugin

1. Which programming languages are not supported by Eclipse?
2. How do we change this fact?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a list of things what will potentially become out of date very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I dont know.... BrainF**k + whitespace, probably. But I think you really care about #2.

2) [Make your own](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=370625).

There are a slew of articles if you google for "eclipse for a new language"

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sure does support alot of them, but it does a pretty bad job at most of them.   Notepad++ supports about  75 languages, but I really wouldn't use it as an IDE for most of them.  I think this is the weak point of Eclipse.  It tries to support every language under the sun.  But for a lot of languages, there are much better tools out there, that are also free.  Personally, I don't think it's the best IDE for any language.

Answer (score 0):

At least the following:  MAX/MSP, Pd, Oz, AutoHotkey, PDDL, most of the dialects of Prolog (only three or four dialects are supported).  Mathematica is only supported via a commercial eclipse-*based* IDE.  (Wolfram Workbench.)  I'm sure others know examples which are less obscure, however :-)

Answer (score -1):

It does not have decent SQLJ support.

Comment: There is not a plugin for Eclipse, however IBM Data Studio that is based on Eclipse support SQLJ completely.

Comment: But my answer is still true about Eclipse. Anyway, it was certainly true in February 2009.